# Override buttons from parent class in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, overriding, parent

is there any way to override buttons in xaml file which is child of my parent class? or what is the best way to get chield buttons in parent class?

Comment: Override? Like the style? the functionality? Visually override? If you really want an answer, you should read the stackoverflow faq on ["How to ask questions"](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), and improve your question.

Comment: u have some xaml file with buttons and u want to assign different actions to these buttons u need to override it